# ¿Cómo cambiar de "Pantalla" con QStackedWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

### Hola a todos!

Estoy iniciandome en PyQT5 y tengo el siguiente problema:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
Icon = "Icon.png"
Title = "SisGrab Beta"
    class MainW(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainW, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle(Title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(Icon))
        self.resize(600,200)
        #self.showMaximized()

        self.Pantalla_Menu()
        #self.Pantalla_Prueba()

        self.Pantalla_Menu = QWidget()
        #self.Pantalla_Prueba = QWidget()

        self.Stack = QStackedWidget(self)
        self.Stack.addWidget (self.Pantalla_Menu)
        #self.Stack.addWidget (self.Pantalla_Prueba)

        self.show()

    def Pantalla_Menu(self):
        #Caja1 = QVBoxLayout(self)
        Button1 = QPushButton("Ingresar al Sistema de Grabados", self);Button1.setGeometry(0,50,170,40)
        # Caja1.addWidget(Button1)
        Button2 = QPushButton("Información", self);Button2.setGeometry(0,100,170,40)
        # Caja1.addWidget(Button2)
        Button3 = QPushButton("Opciones", self);Button3.setGeometry(0,150,170,40)
        # Caja1.addWidget(Button3)
        Button4 = QPushButton("Salir", self);Button4.setGeometry(0,200,170,40)
        # Caja1.addWidget(Button4)

        Button1.clicked.connect(self.Pantalla_Prueba)
        Button4.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
    def Pantalla_Prueba(self):
        Button = QLabel("Hola")

def Main():
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Wnd = MainW()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())

if __name__=='__main__':
    Main()
```

Necesitaría hacer que, al presionar el botón llamado "Button1", se "limpie la ventana" y aparezca otra sección. No se si me explico...

Ejemplo:

PANTALLA 1: Contiene el menú principal.
            Al presionar el botón 1, cambiar a pantalla 2

PANTALLA 2: Contiene imágenes.
            En construcción

**NOTA -->** No estoy hablando de MessageWindow ni nada por el estilo.

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Explicate correctamente que es lo que deseas hacer.

Comment: Es muy simple. No creo que haga falta explicar lo que quiero que haga el programa en su totalidad, pero... Quiero hacer como en las aplicaciones de Android (Un ejemplo un tanto simple). Quiero que al tocar un botón, se muestre otra interfaz. O sea que, al tocar un botón, se oculten y se muestren otros.

Comment: Okay, te entiendo, pero siempre es bueno dar una explicacion clara de lo que se desea, estoy implementando la solucion, pero antes de ello de tedo decir que es una muy mal practica de programacion llamar a una variables y a un metodo con el mismo nombre: miembro de la clase: `self.Pantalla_Menu = QWidget()` y metodo: `def Pantalla_Menu(self):`

Comment: Wow! No me dí cuenta! Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de iniciar con la descripción de la solucion debo indicar que es una  mala practica de programacion llamar a una variables y a un metodo con el mismo nombre:

miembro de la clase:

```
self.Pantalla_Menu = QWidget()
```

y metodo:

```
def Pantalla_Menu(self):
```

Tambien me permiti reestructurar el proyecto para darle un orden adecuado, para ello he creado un widget por cada pantalla.

Como estas usando QStackedWidget y deseas de cambiar de pantalla solo debes cambiar el currentIndex a traves del metodo setCurrentIndex(), el index se crea consecutivamente cada vez que usas el metodo addWidget(), por lo que para tener un codigo entendible almacenaremos esa variable y la usaremos posteriormente, esta cambio del currentIndex se debe dar cuando la señal clicked se emita, como la tarea es sencilla usaremos una funcion lambda:

```
Icon = "Icon.png"
Title = "SisGrab Beta"

class Pantalla_Menu(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        hlay = QHBoxLayout(self)
        vlay = QVBoxLayout()
        hlay.addLayout(vlay)
        hlay.addItem(QSpacerItem(687, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum))

        self.button1 = QPushButton("Ingresar al Sistema de Grabados", self)
        button2 = QPushButton("Información", self)
        button3 = QPushButton("Opciones", self)
        button4 = QPushButton("Salir", self)
        vlay.addWidget(self.button1)
        vlay.addWidget(button2)
        vlay.addWidget(button3)
        vlay.addWidget(button4)
        button4.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

class Pantalla_Prueba(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        hlay = QHBoxLayout(self)
        label = QLabel("label", self)
        hlay.addWidget(label)

class MainW(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainW, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle(Title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(Icon))
        self.resize(600,200)
        self.pantalla_menu = Pantalla_Menu(self)
        self.pantalla_prueba = Pantalla_Prueba(self)
        self.stack = QStackedWidget(self)
        ix_pantalla_menu = self.stack.addWidget(self.pantalla_menu)
        ix_pantalla_prueba = self.stack.addWidget(self.pantalla_prueba)

        self.pantalla_menu.button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stack.setCurrentIndex(ix_pantalla_prueba))
        self.show()
```

Comment: Wow! Muchísimas Gracias!

Todavía soy nuevo en esto! Por el momento lo entiendo y es lo que busco!

Gracias y perdón por las molestias!

Comment: @MathiasHilgert Te recomiendo leer el PEP8 para mejorar la legibilidad de tu codigo: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Igual fué un código que lo hice muy rápido :D ... Eso me pasa por despistado!